# Modified Memorystream Byte length less than when its saved

Tags: c#, .net, file, io, stream

I'm loading in a binary file into a memory stream and modifying the bytes and then storing the file to disk. However to save time I retain the modified byte array to calculate a checksum. When I load the saved file from disk and calculate the checksum the file length is about 150 bytes different from the original byte length when it was saved and obviously the checksum doesn't match the one before it was saved. Any ideas as to why this happens? I've searched and searched for clues but it looks like I'd have to reload the file after it was saved to calculate an accurate checksum.

Also note that the shorter byte array does render its contents correctly and so does the longer byte array, in fact the two arrays render identically!

Here's the code that collects the modified bytes from the memory stream:

```
writerStream.Flush();
storedFile = new Byte[writerStream.Length];
writerStream.Position = 0;
writerStream.Read(storedFile, 0, Convert.ToInt32(writerStream.Length));
```

And here's how I read the file:

```
using (BinaryReader readFile = new BinaryReader(Delimon.Win32.IO.File.Open(filePath, Delimon.Win32.IO.FileMode.Open)))
        {
            byte[] cgmBytes = readFile.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(readFile.BaseStream.Length));
            hash = fileCheck.ComputeHash(cgmBytes);                
        }
```

And here's how the file is saved:

```
     (using BinaryWriter aWriter = new BinaryWriter(Delimon.Win32.IO.File.Create(filePath))
     {

          aWriter.Write(storedFile);

     }
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thx

Comment: `Stream.Read` is only gaunteed to read ***up to*** the value you passed in to the 3rd parameter. You must read the result of the call and loop as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the write has finished there isn't any other bytes to read. So the writestream.Length is the total bytes written. Also the save of the file is the storedFile byte array which, as an example, is 379528 bytes, but when I read the file that was saved as 379528 bytes it has 379698. It doesn't make sense that the saved file has more bytes than what I saved it as.

Comment: Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. There is simply not enough information here to provide you with an answer. Heck, you don't even show the code _where you write the file_, which seems like an important detail to me.

Comment: I've added the code where the file is saved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have resolved itself by simply changing the point where the stream position is set:

```
                writerStream.Flush();
                writerStream.Position = 0; 
                storedFile = new Byte[writerStream.Length];
                writerStream.Read(storedFile, 0, Convert.ToInt32(writerStream.Length));
```

In the previous code the Position was set after reading the stream length, now the position is set before reading the stream length. In either case the byte length DOES NOT CHANGE, but the saved file when retrieved returns the identical byte length now. Why? Not sure, setting the stream position does not affect the stream length nor should it affect how a newly instantiated writer decides to save the byte array. Gremlins?...